# The service "sylius.validator.variant.unique"

Tags: sylius

A few days ago i posted here a same question when i got this error:sylius.currency_importer.open_exchange_rates of wich i get the answer here and i resolve these by putting the class in parameters.yml,and all went nice!!today i get the same problem, the errror is:The service "sylius.validator.variant.unique" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sylius.repository.variant".
i tried to put the calss in the parameters.yml but it doesn't work can everyone help me please:Thank you for your answers!

Comment: did you found any solution, I am facing the same problem now

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for variation bundle here [syliusvariationbundle](http://sylius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusVariationBundle/index.html)

Can you post the results for the following command please : `php app/console container:debug | grep variant`

You need to define the repository class for the sylius.repository.variant service which will provide product variants for your application.